# Django Server Does not affect view changes

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, server, gunicorn

I m using Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04 to serve my Django project.

I configured everything [( like here )](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) properly and working so well, but I noticed that changes in my views doesn't affect my server side, although template changes are applied.

**This is my scenario :**

---

**First Commit :**

*service.views.py :*

```
def showSudent(req):
  student = Student.objects.get(pk=1)
  return render(req, 'bio.html, { 'student' : student} )
```

*template/bio.html :*

```
<h3>{{ student.firstName }}</h3>
```

---

**Second Commit :**

*service.views.py :*

```
def showSudent(req):
  student = Student.objects.get(pk=1)
  return render(req, 'student.html, { 'student' : student} )
```

*template/bio.html :*

```
<h3>{{ student.lastName }}</h3>
```

---

I changed views and template both and pull them to server.

So now, django is still renders '**bio**.html' ( but it must render '**student**.html' ) , by the time interestingly it shows 'student.**lastName**' now.

***It means, django sees my template changes but not views changes.***

I repeatedly checked everything is right on server, yes all codes are right at server but not affects any view changes although all my templates changes are affected.

Also I restarted nginx, even rebooted the server several times.

What is the problem with that ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to restart Gunicorn and Nginx

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn nginx
```

Comment: Deleted server , and reconfigured everything. And now, yes this works properly. I dont know still why it was not working with previous server . I had tried this many times but not worked there, but in new server its ok.

Comment: I always restart both `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn nginx`

Comment: Took me a couple of hours to get here, but this was exactly the solution I was missing ! I was only restarting nginx, not gunicorn.

Answer (score 1):

By default gunicorn required restart application manually, there is another option which won't fit for production environment running gunicorn with `--reload` argument like:

```
$ gunicorn wsgi:application --reload
```

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload